# How can I resolve .Net SDK related issue?

Tags: .net

I am getting some .Net SDK related error. My dot net core is 2.1.5. I am not sure why it throws me error.When I build I got only this error.

"The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1.  Either target .NET Core 1.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.1"

How to resolve this? All the references also disable means it shows blue triangle.

Comment: It's a bit too broad question to answer, but try to update sdk/nuget packages.

Comment: The SDK version is distinct from the .NETCore runtime version.  You may have to update your VS version to get the build tools you need.  Or lower the target version, the combobox shows the .NETCore versions it knows about.